# Design pattern - Singleton pattern in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, design-patterns, singleton

I'm following this [article](https://omamazainab.hashnode.dev/part-02-singleton). I understood what singleton pattern is but I'm not be able to understand the code.

```
let Singleton = (function(){
    let instance = null;

    function createInstance() {
        let obj = new Object("I am the new instance");
        return obj;
    }

    return {
        getInstance:function() {
            console.log(instance);
            if(instance === null) {
                instance = createInstance();
            }
            return instance;
        }
    }
})();

function test() {
    let instance1 = Singleton.getInstance();
    let instance2 = Singleton.getInstance();
    console.log(Object.is(instance1,instance2));
}
test();
```

why instance1 and instance2 are same, we are always initializing the instance to ***null*** whenever we call `Singleton`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> we are always initializing the instance to null whenever we call `Singleton`.

You do not. `Singleton` is the object in the `return` statement, which does not include the statement `let instance = null`. This statement is only executed once; this variable is captured under [closure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_(computer_programming)) in `getInstance` method of the returned object (`Singleton.getInstance`). The code is equivalent to

```
let instance = null;

function createInstance() {
    let obj = new Object("I am the new instance");
    return obj;
}

let Singleton = {
    getInstance: function() {
        console.log(instance);
        if (instance === null) {
            instance = createInstance();
        }
        return instance;
    }
}
```

except that `instance` and `createInstance` are hidden inside the [IIFE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately_invoked_function_expression)'s scope.

You can verify how many times (and when) `let instance = null` executes by inserting more logging statements.

Comment: Got it, I was interpreting Singleton as a function but is actually an object with getInstance property. Thank you Amadan.